# Apache Geode Pulse WAR File

Tags: geode

I am following the Apache Geode [build instructions](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/BUILDING.md) to build the project. My environment is Windows 10.

What I am actually interested is to get Geode Pulse WAR artifact from the build. However, the build is not successful because of errors like this,

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':geode-core:integrationTestCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find log4j-core-tests.jar (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/james/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1/log4j-core-2.11.1-tests.jar
   > Could not find log4j-core-test-sources.jar (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/james/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1/log4j-core-2.11.1-test-sources.jar
```

How do I skip all the tests including integration tests or continue to build with tests failure? I have tried `gradlew build -x test` but it broke with the same build error. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue in the past and I believe it's related to your local `MAVEN` repository, not to `Geode`. Can you try to entirely remove the folder `C:/Users/james/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1` and try again?, `MAVEN` will surely download the jar from scratch and everything should work fine.

Cheers.

Comment: alright, i will "remove" the whole .m2 for the time being and try again.

Comment: You don't need to remove the entire `.m2` directory, that will delete the entire local maven repository!. Just delete the one folder related to your failure (`C:/Users/james/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1`).

Comment: What I showed you just one of the many error messages. Instead of hunting down all the directories i just rename my .m2 directory. I want to quickly verify that this is the cause of my problem. I will fix it later. yes, it it seems that it is an issue with .m2 . Thanks